# What are best practices for managing and verifying application-level roles in a Google Apps application?

Tags: google-apps

What are best practices for maintaining roles (e.g., a `user-provisioning` role) in a Web application that uses OAuth 2.0 authentication against a Google App domain?  These are roles that are tied to a specific Web application, rather than to the domain as a whole.

Is role management at the application level typically done using the application's backend database, once the OAuth Web flow authorization has been completed?  I was thinking of using a Google App group to stand in for each role and then verify membership in the group using the Directory API before allowing an action to be carried out.  Is this a suitable approach?  This requires either a service account with a group-membership privilege or the assigning of such a privilege to each user in the domain with that role, which are steps that would be nice to avoid.

Is there an API to read information about Google App's native domain-level roles for this?  Should custom properties on the user's profile be used?  If the latter, is there a straightforward way for a domain admin to set these up when provisioning a new user in the domain, or will a separate UI need to be built out?  I've noticed that in the user profile information there is a `isDelegatedAdmin` field, but that field is a boolean, and I have not found anything with more granular information on the roles delegated to the user account.